# Replacing audio file for AKAudioPlayer playback not working

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit, akaudioplayer

I have an app in which I want to have a single audio player, and the ability to switch out what audio clips are in the player. Currently using `AKAudioPlayer` and `replace(file: audioFile)`.

I have the following class that gets created on the view controller loading:

```
class AudioFilePlayer {
    var songFile = Bundle.main
    var player: AKAudioPlayer!


    func play(file: String, type: String)    {
        var audioFile: AKAudioFile!
        let song = songFile.path(forResource: file, ofType: type)

        do {
            let url = URL(string: song!)
            audioFile = try AKAudioFile(forReading: url!)
        } catch {
            AKLog(error)
        }

        do {
            player = try AKAudioPlayer(file: audioFile)
        } catch {
            AKLog(error)
        }

    }

    func rePlay(file: String, type: String) {
        var audioFile: AKAudioFile!
        let song = songFile.path(forResource: file, ofType: type)

        do {
            let url = URL(string: song!)
            audioFile = try AKAudioFile(forReading: url!)
        } catch {
            AKLog(error)
        }

        do {
           try player.replace(file: audioFile)

        } catch {
            AKLog(error)
        }
    }

    func pause(){
        player.pause()
    }
}
```

Once the app starts, I have the following code to set up the AK signal chain and create a player with an audio file, and I immediately pause it:

```
audioFilePlayer.play(file: "Breathing_01", type: ".mp3")
audioFilePlayer.player.looping = false

AudioKit.output = audioFilePlayer.player

do {
          try AudioKit.start()
      } catch {
          AKLog("AudioKit did not start!")
      }
audioFilePlayer.player.play()
audioFilePlayer.pause()
```

Elsewhere in the app, I have the following code to replace the audio file used in the player:

```
self.audioFilePlayer.player.pause()
self.audioFilePlayer.rePlay(file: "Breathing_01", type: "mp3")
self.audioFilePlayer.player.play()
```

When I run the app and initiate the process of trying to replace the file, I see this log:

```
2020-04-05 17:32:13.674413-0700 Mindful[24081:4439478] [general] AKAudioPlayer.swift:replace(file:):397:AKAudioPlayer -> File with "Breathing_01.mp3" Reloaded (AKAudioPlayer.swift:replace(file:):397)
2020-04-05 17:32:13.686119-0700 Mindful[24081:4439478] [general] AKAudioPlayer.swift:startTime:171:AKAudioPlayer.startTime = 0.0, startingFrame: 0 (AKAudioPlayer.swift:startTime:171)
2020-04-05 17:32:14.282632-0700 Mindful[24081:4439478] [general] AKAudioPlayer.swift:updatePCMBuffer():570:read 13359773 frames into buffer (AKAudioPlayer.swift:updatePCMBuffer():570)
```

But no audio output at all. When setting breakpoints, I can confirm that my player is playing, but have no audio.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Doing the following fixed it:

```
try player.replace(file: audioFile)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.player.play(from: 0)
}
```